# Issues with KBPC5010 rectifier

Tags: full-bridge

I recently ordered some [KBPC5010 full bridge rectifiers from Amazon,](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MQ65HLB) and I am not getting the behavior I expected.

I am most likely missing something here, but am unsure if the Amazon product may be faulty. I have successfully made full bridge rectifiers before in a circuits class using individual diodes, so I assume this pre-packaged thing may not be what I think it is.

Expected behavior with no filtering capacitor:

[image]

Expected behavior with filtering capacitor:

[image]

Observed behavior with no filtering capacitor:

[image]

Observed behavior with filtering capacitor:

[image]

Circuit and probe setup with 3V AC in:

[image]

What circuit I think I have:

[image]

The waveform shown above is not simply a few volts in magnitude due to inadequate filtering. It spans the entire output voltage range. The filtering capacitor a 1000uf electrolytic capacitor.

Comment: Likely you are just connecting it to an incorrect circuit. But you don't tell the circuit details where is it connected to. Is the 3 Vac source by any chance a grounded signal generator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Full Bridge Rectifier Oscilloscope Reading](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/507428/full-bridge-rectifier-oscilloscope-reading)

Comment: Sketch on paper the physical bridge pins and where the diodes should be connected.  Then use a multimeter, on diode-check mode, to identify the diodes in the bridge.  Perhaps it is mis-labeled.  In general though, Amazon is a risk for electronic components.

Comment: Just and JRE - My circuit is isolated through a variable transformer, so I don't believe that the issue is the ground connection between the transformer and scope

Comment: rdtsc - I have flipped all of the connections and checked every wiring configuration. I am starting to think that this may be a full wave rectifier that was mis-represented on amazon as a full bridge rectifier.

Comment: A variable transformer is usually an *auto-transformer* and does not isolate. Don't connect the scope ground, use your 2 scope probes in a differential mode. Use both scope probes and a math function on the scope (chan1 - chan2). Be sure to set both channels on the same vertical scale.

Comment: Mattman944 - I will try that thank you. I was unaware that the variable transformer did not provide galvanic isolation. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Highly doubt there is anything wrong with [those](http://www.sep-semi.com/en/02product/01search/0102ProSer/010207%20bridge/010207%20bridge_400.htm) bridge rectifiers (other than an overly optimistic current rating - at case temperature only 40°C for this manufacturer.

Comment: @zraxix: " I am starting to think that this may be a full wave rectifier that was mis-represented on amazon as a full bridge rectifier."  Those are both the same thing.